# Is there a way of obtaining the Xpath position of highlighted text using Windows Form Application in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xpath, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I am trying to create a webscraper tool using Windows Form Application. Is there an API or method to display the exact xpath position of selected text? So far I have written code which allows me to  highlight text on a navigated website in webbrowser control, and to output this highlighted text into a richtextbox using ContextMenuStrip.

The code I have written below is:

---

```
 private void getSelectedTextToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
        IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = htmlDocument.selection;
        if (currentSelection != null)
        {
            IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
            if (range != null)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = range.htmlText;
            }
```

The button navigates to the website below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5EFTSE");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
        webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;          
    }
```

So far it does exactly what I want it to do. However, I now wish to obtain the xpath position of whatever is highlighted, as opposed to just outputting the text content. The idea is that if I want to extract live data (*i.e. market data on the Yahoo Finance webpage*), the data on the website is constantly changing so I am interested in getting the position within the html page structure. Any ideas on whether this is possible and what steps I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you will have to build the XPath yourself by going up the hierarchy from the selected element, by doing something like the following:

```
private void getSelectedXPathToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
    IHTMLElement selectedElement = null;
    var sel = doc.selection;
    if (sel.type == "Text")
        selectedElement = ((IHTMLTxtRange)sel.createRange()).parentElement();
    else if (sel.type == "Control")
        selectedElement = ((IHTMLControlRange)sel.createRange()).commonParentElement();

    var node = (IHTMLDOMNode)selectedElement;
    MessageBox.Show(GetXPath(node, true));
}

string GetXPath(IHTMLDOMNode node, bool stopAtId)
{
    var path = new Stack<string>();
    while (node != null && node as IHTMLDocument2 == null)
    {
        var index = 0;
        // find previous siblings with the same tag name
        var prev = node.previousSibling;
        while (prev != null)
        {
            if (prev.nodeType == 1 && prev.nodeName == node.nodeName)
                index++;
            prev = prev.previousSibling;
        }
        var showIndex = index > 0;
        // if there were none, find if there are any next siblings with the same tag name
        var next = node.nextSibling;
        while (next != null)
        {
            if (next.nodeType == 1 && next.nodeName == node.nodeName)
            {
                showIndex = true;
                break;
            }
            next = next.nextSibling;
        }
        var id = ((IHTMLDOMAttribute2)((IHTMLAttributeCollection2)node.attributes).getNamedItem("id")).value;
        if (id != string.Empty)
        {
            showIndex = false;
        }
        var part = node.nodeName + (showIndex ? string.Format("[{0}]", index + 1) : string.Empty) + (id != string.Empty ? string.Format("[@id = '{0}']", id) : string.Empty);
        if (id != string.Empty && stopAtId)
            part = "/" + part;
        path.Push(part);
        if (id != string.Empty && stopAtId)
            break;
        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    return "/" + string.Join("/", path);
}
```

In this example, I have created a new method called `getSelectedXPathToolStripMenuItem_Click`, which would correspond to a new menu item on your context menu, to display the XPath at the selection in a message box.  Obviously, you can change this to put it in your RTB if you want.

The main work is done in the `GetXPath` method, which does the DOM traversal. It checks the previous siblings, to determine the index of the node, and if it is the first sibling with that name, it checks next siblings too, to see if the index (1) should be included.

It also accepts a boolean parameter called `stopAtId`, which, as the name suggests, will stop traversing the DOM when the node has the `id` attribute set.  This could be useful because you can always easily find an element by it's id, without needing to know anything about it's ancestors etc.